# How should we combine multiple datasets without duplicates in rows or columns when we have no common column names in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am a beginner in data analysis and I want to join 3 tables into one without duplicate rows or columns. I have a column in all 3 tables with similar values but the names of column is different in 3 tables. 
I have 3 tables `'listings'`, `'users'`,`'info'`. All of them have ID numbers as common but it has different column name like 'user_id' in listings table, 'id' in users table and 'id_number' in info table.

I tried the following but still I get either duplicate values or NaN values.

```
pd.merge(listings,users,left_on='user_id',right_on='id').merge(info,left_on='user_id',right_on='id_number')
```

for this case I see duplicate values and also the total rows are very less in the result.

I tried concat as below:

```
pd.concat(['listings','users','info'],axis=1)
```

but I got the below error:

> TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type ""; only
>   pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `pd.merge` without supplying the **how** argument, you are performing an `inner` join on the two tables.And since `inner` joins are **a kind of mathematical `intersection`**, you should expect to see fewer than or equal to the number of rows in the smaller table.

When you do

```
pd.merge(listings,users,left_on='user_id',right_on='id').merge(info,left_on='user_id',right_on='id_number')
```

you are bound to have `duplicate columns`. The two columns `id` and `user_id` are going to appear in the results of the first merger and when you perform the second merge, the two columns `user_id` and `id_number` will appear. These are all duplicates of one column.

If all three tables had the same `ID`, you would not be seeing the duplicate columns. I think you should just drop the duplicate columns. I believe you would be able to figure out the origin of the duplicate columns with ease if you had saved the results of the first merge in one dataframe and then perform the final merge with the `info` table.